# Can I use "C'est" the same way as "Est-ce", why not if so?

Tags: grammaire, questions

Example:

*Est-ce quelqu'un qui vous rendre un service ?*

vs.

*C'est quelqu'un qui vous rendre un service ?*

Comment: Hi, I meant "lend a hand" in English. Rendre service is what I meant - thank you & apologies for the direct spanish-french translation. I have modified the question accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both work fine as questions but I'd like to point out that it is not because you are using *C'est* the same way as *Est-ce*. It's just  the way you phrase it I'm objecting to, for grammar's sake.

You can ask a question:

- Just by adding a question mark to the affirmative sentence (and when speaking the intonation differs):
  *C'est quelqu'un qui vous prête un service* ?
- By having the subject before the verb:
  *Est-ce quelqu'un qui vous prête un service ?*
  (*ce* stands for *c'*, no elision possible here)

Another question could have been:

- *Est-ce que c'est quelqu'un qui vous prête un service* ?
  Where you just add *est-ce que* in front of the affirmative sentence. Which is very frequent in oral speech, you can write it too, it's just less formal than the inversion.

*Prêter un service* is not very clear and that's probably not what you mean. You might mean *rendre service* (do a favour/lend a hand) or *proposer/fournir un service* (provide a service).

---

Edit after [OP's comment](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/49559/can-i-use-cest-the-same-way-as-est-ce-why-not-if-so/49560#comment101623_49559):

- *C'est quelqu'un qui vous rend (un) service ?*
- *Est-ce quelqu'un qui vous rend (un) service ?*
- *Est-ce que c'est quelqu'un qui vous rend (un) service* ?

Comment: Are you more likely to say prêter un service over rendre (un) service in Québecois? This is just a simple question. [I do not need snark from other posters].

Answer (score 1):

« Est-ce quelqu’un qui vous rend service ? » c’est écrit dans un style formel alors que « C’est quelqu’un… ? » est dans un style familier.